# Render a CCK field with only the node object in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, entities, theming, nodes

If I have a node object and would like to render just a given CCK field, how would I do so? I don't mean on a node template page or in a nodeapi hook, just in general.

My custom CCK field's `theme_mymodule_formatter_default` function takes an $elements array - when this function is called on the node page, $elements is an array with keys including the following:

- #formatter
- #node
- #field_name
- #theme
- 0
- 1

...where 0 and 1 point to arrays of values in the multi-valued CCK field.

Now if I want to render this field, and all I have is my formatter function and a node object, how do I format it? If I call `theme('mymodule_formatter', $node->field_my_cck_field[0])`, what gets passed to the $elements array of my formatter function is an array with only the following keys

- 0
- 1

But rather than even having to call the theme() method, I'd like to call something like drupal_render() that will pick the default theme formatter function. I imagine there's a way to do something like this, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

In D6, you can render CCK fields with:

[content_format](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!cck!content.module/function/content_format/6)

e.g:

```
print content_format('field_my_cck_field', $node->field_my_cck_field[0], 'default', $node);
```

See also [content_view_field](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!cck!content.module/function/content_view_field/6) for an alternative option.

If you're in a node template and the field is set to display, you can also just go:

```
print $FIELD_NAME_rendered // where $FIELD_NAME is the field name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$field = content_fields('field_my_cck_field', $node->type);
$rendered_field = content_view_field($field, $node, FALSE, TRUE);
```

Comment: Hello. It's usually a good idea to post a bit more than a code in your answer. A bit of explanation, links to api docs and so on.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Rendering a cck field with the div wrappers that they normally come with.

Answer (score 1):

**Rendering CCK Field values in Drupal 6.x**

If you have a copy of the node and you need to output the rendered value of a field or fields, then you need to

1. Set the view mode to either 'full' or 'teaser'
2. Push the node through node_build_content
3. Output the 'view' key of the fields you want to render

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$nid = 12345;
$node = node_load($nid);

if ($teaser_view_is_what_you_want) {
    $build_mode = NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW;
    $teaser = TRUE;
    $page = FALSE;
else {
    $build_mode = NODE_BUILD_NORMAL;
    $teaser = FALSE;
    $page = TRUE;
}

$node->build_mode = $build_mode;
$node = node_build_content($node, $teaser, $page);

content_alter($node);

echo $node->field_myfield[0]['view'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The funcitons field_view_value() and field_view_field() may help you in this case?

Have a link on this article about these functions: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Comment: I should have mentioned it's Drupal 6 I'm working with. I have updated the thread title to reflect this.

Comment: The question says D6.

Comment: And he says that he changed the title to d6 after i posted the answer.

Comment: whopsie daisy :)